# Export an env variable on windows

Tags: javascript, node.js, windows, macos, command-line-interface

I took over a project built in node and Js. To get the program to run, i have to export my environment variable through my command prompt. It exports to firebase which creates an instance to run . It works on mac, but not on windows.am trying to export my env variable using the cli in windows. On mac, I can simply run:

`export env=test`

But on Windows it doesn’t recognize that. It also doesn’t recognize set. Anyone know how to fix?

Comment: Unfortunately no.

Comment: If that doesn't work, please edit your question to include more details about what you're trying to do. Are you trying to do this in a `package.json` script?